# Ошибка компиляции макроса

Tags: c, макросы

Почему не компилируется данный фрагмент кода?

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, field_name) ( \
(type *) ((char *) (ptr) - offsetof(type, field_name)))
```

Выдает ошибку

> C:\list.h:37: ошибка: expected expression before ')' token
>        (type * )((char *) (ptr) - offsetof(type, field_name)))
>                ^

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такой

```
#define container_of(field_addr,type,field_name)    \
  ((type *)((char *)field_addr -                    \
            (char *)&((type *)0)->field_name))
```

у меня работает.

---

После того, как в пастебине появился исходник, все встало на место.

Оба макроса работают, только компилировать надо `gcc -std=gnu99 ...` (а не `-std=c99`, поскольку оператор `typeof()` является расширением GNU и не воспринимается в C99).

Comment: Выдает ту же самую ошибку.
Значит и ваш фрагмент кода правильный и мой, дело не в синтаксисе, а в компиляторе.Что может быть не так?gcc 4.9.2; -std=c99

Comment: @djkah11,  странно. Приведите законченный фпагмент кода. У меня `gcc.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4` Ваш не работает (с такой же ошибкой) (а мой работает). Думаю дело в том, что макрос `offsetof` не определен (искать где он, неохота).

Comment: Ребята, макросы НЕ КОМПИЛИРУЮТСЯ. Надо смотреть куда он вставляется. В дефайне вы можете написать ВООБЩЕ все что угодно.

Comment: @andy.37, это и ежу понятно.

Comment: К сожалению, у меня многовато кода. Но вдруг....
http://pastebin.com/r4srkBDW Сама программка, ничего интересного.
http://pastebin.com/kuxvJvgH  - Заголовок для работы с списками(линуксовский).
Вот при попытке скомпилировать программу с этой библиотекой, выскакивает вышеописанная ошибка с указанием на вышеприведенную строчку.

Comment: @djkah11, я скомпилировал (и Ваш и мой варианты). Только с -std=gnu99 (а не c99 (с ним в самом деле не компилируется из-за `typeof`)).